# JQuery css max-height not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tested this code for set `.css('max-height','auto')` css property in JQuery but it's not working, and when I set a dimension like `.css('max-height','93px')` it's working fine, how can I set it as `auto` ?

HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div>DIVISION</div>
    <div>DIVISION</div>
    <div>DIVISION</div>
    <div>DIVISION</div>
    <div>DIVISION</div>
    <div>DIVISION</div>
    <div>DIVISION</div>
</div>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="test();" value="CHECK" />
```

CSS:

```
.holder{
    max-height:40px;
    background:red;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.holder div{
    background:blue;
    margin:3px 0;
}
```

js:

```
function test(){
    var hldr=$('.holder'); //get element

    alert('before set: ' + $('.holder').css('max-height')); //alert before set

    /* SET */
    hldr.css('max-height','auto');

    alert('after set: ' + $('.holder').css('max-height'));//alert after set
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silverlight/23UCV/2/

Comment: There is no `max-height:auto` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height. Just use `height:auto`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `max-height` to `height` fixes your problem.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23UCV/3/)

Answer (score 12):

I have also faced the same problem.

I have tried the **maxHeight** property. Now the problem has been resolved

```
$('#exampleId').css({"maxHeight":"100px"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if earlier browsers had this issue. Tested recently in Chrome 56.x, FF 51.0.x and IE 11, you can use:

```
max-height: none;
```

so this works

```
alert('after set: ' + $('.holder').css('max-height','none'));//alert after set
```

One can use this as well with jquery (tested with 2.0.3) and create a toggle

```
$('#someid').toggleClass("expand");
```

and css

```
.expand{
   max-height: none !important;
}
```

Comment: how is it different than other answers